# Right outer join using Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am to new to Entity Framework. Please help me with the following query.

I have 2 tables, Users and Companies and I need to make a right outer join on Users table.

Here is what I have right now.

```
List<Company> users = DbContext.Companies                        
                    .Where(p => !p.User.IsDeleted)
                    .Include(p=> p.User)
                    .OrderBy(p => p.User.FirstName)
                    .ToList();
```

Please help me out. TIA.

Relationship is User.id = Company.Companyid

Sample Data

```
Name         Role             Userid         Companyid
Test1 Test1  User             210            210
Test2 Test2  User             1034           1034
Test3 Test3  Company Admin    2594           2594
Test4 Test4  Company Admin    5139           5139
```

Expected Result

```
    Name            Role            Userid    Companyid
    Test1 Test1     User            210       210
    Test2 Test2     User            1034      1034
    Test3 Test3     Company Admin   2594      2594
    Test4 Test4     Company Admin   5139      5139
    Test5 Test5     Super Admin     1         Null
```

Comment: what is key, relationship between 2 table? show your sample data and what's your expectation?

Comment: Your sample data doesn't seem to show Users and Companies tables, just one table. Also your Expected Result shows data not in the sample data. Try again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
var usercompany = from u in dbcontext.User  
             join c in DbContext.Companies.Include(c=>c.User) 
             on u.id equals c.id into cu 
             from co in cu.DefaultIfEmpty() 
             select new   
             {
                u.id,
                co.id
             };
var result= usercompany.ToList()
```

Comment: Yeah, but using the `join` statement shouldn't be promoted at the expense of using navigation properties.

Comment: we can include the navigation property with in join Check my revised code above

Comment: What I mean is that you should remove the `join` statement.

Comment: if we use Include the query will generate Inner Join. another way in EF core 2.1 create view with navigation property  and use view and add include

Comment: @GertArnold Why would `Include()` be preferred over a `join`? General advice appears to avoid `Include` for performance reasons, I have never heard the like about `join`.

Comment: @Beltway You better ask: why not? `Include` will use navigation properties that, in fact , are joins as defined in the model. Why would you use an error-prone join statement all the time if there is a navigation property? As for performance: "avoid `Include`" is not the general advice, it's "avoid *many* `Includes`". The same goes for joins.

Comment: @GertArnold I see, I occasionally go for `join` in certain edge cases where there are no Navigations configured. but it's reliving to hear there is no additional overhead or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can query like

```
List<User> users = DbContext.Users.Include(p => p.Company).Where(p => !p.IsDeleted).ToList();
```

it will load users and company. if user is mapped to any company EF will load company as well. if user is not mapped to any company it will be company property will remain null.

Answer (score -1):

If I have not understood you wrong then below ways :

```
List<Company> users = DbContext.Companies   
                     .Include(p=> p.User)                     
                     .Where(p => !p.User.IsDeleted && p.User.CompanyId == p.CompnayId)                  
                     .OrderBy(p => p.User.FirstName)
                     .ToList();
```

OR

```
List<User> users = DbContext.Users.Include(p => p.Company).Where(p => !p.IsDeleted && p.CompanyId == p.Company.CompanyId).ToList();
```

Comment: It Just brings only the inner join result not the expected right outer join.

Comment: What result you want to get ? Not deleted Users Company wise ? Right ?

Comment: I want to retrieve all the users from User table regardless of Company table where the flag of Isdeleted in User table should be false.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Mine is a code first approach. So, what exactly it has is, In the User Entity, I just have its fields like Firstname, lastname, Isdeleted etc. and in the Company entity I have something like below  Public virtual User User {get;set;} . So I had to query like above. Please let me know if it makes sense. The Query that I used works perfect but the thing is, it just works as an inner join. I see something like .Join<> and I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Your will definately get the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107194/how-to-implement-entity-framework-code-first-join) !